# How to chnage default timeout duration in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, timeout, database-connection

*I just want to how can I change the global timeout duration and how can I test it.*

I've some queries that I believe to change the defaul timeout duration, like;

```
SET GLOBAL max_execution_time = 4;
```

> I think if I set max_execution_time = 4 , and if my query will executing in 5 sec I 'll get timeout error.
> I just tried some queries for testing. I wondered if I apply to default imeout to 4 sec;

```
DO SLEEP(5);

SELECT SLEEP(5);
```

also I found a query for test the timeout duration that is;

```
WAITFOR DELAY (5);
```

but didn't work (code throw an error).

After I tried thoose are, I didn't get  the timout error. I expected to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in ***mysql is*** `SELECT SLEEP(5);` while in ***sql is*** `WAITFOR DELAY (5);` that's why it doesn't work.

```
SET GLOBAL max_execution_time = 4;
SELECT SLEEP(5);
```

***Example :*** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/440

Comment: I set global and session max_exec duration. But shouldn't i get timeout error when i run ``` select sleep(10); ```
If I shouldn't get an error how can I understand if its apply ?
Essentially I used this code before but when I didn't get timeout error, I thought like it doesn't work or I can't test it, if its apply.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, max_execution_time uses **milliseconds** as its base unit while the `sleep()` function use seconds . Besides, SET GLOBAL affect the global scope but not the current session. If you want to test it, set the variable value for the session as well.

```
set global max_execution_time = 4000;
set session max_execution_time = 4000;
select sleep(10);
```

The last statement will end as soon as 4 seconds elapses.

Comment: I set global and session max_exec duration. But shouldn't i get timeout error when i run
```
select sleep(10);
```
Essentially I used this code before but when I didn't get timeout error, I thought like it doesn't work or I can't test it, if its apply.